# Optimise the process of saving products programatically

Tags: performance

I am updating everyday the prices/stock data from our stock management system across 9 stores so obviously the process takes a lot of time for thousands of products.

How can I improve the performance?

One improvement that I did was to run the reindex after the import has finished and not on product save. Is there anything else that I can do?

For those experienced, can you share how long does it take for you to update 5000 products programatically (also magento version)?

Answer (score 1):

We have made an extension to import catalog datas in Magento from Akeno PIM, including stocks. (https://github.com/Agence-DnD/PIMGento)
This extension need Akeneo PIM files to work but you can take a look at the Stock importer, fullstack Magento queries to get an idea how to improve performances by direct queries.

---

The idea to avoid data indexation is to save data in the right tables directly.